# Modal react component in material-ui app throwing error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It's my first time working on a React App, and I'm struggling with this error:

```
Portal.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: _reactDom.default.createPortal is not a function
at Portal.render (Portal.js:97)
at vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:30228
at measureLifeCyclePerf (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:29508)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:30227)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:30254)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:30178)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:30156)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:30077)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performUpdateIfNecessary (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:29993)
at Object.performUpdateIfNecessary (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6…sUejeIABZq7AE:12979)
```

These are the imports at my file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { FaceCard } from './FaceCard'
import { Modal } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
```

This is the code that I think is throwing the error:

```
 <Modal
            aria-labelledby="Title"
            aria-describedby="Description"
            open={true}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
            <div>
                <Typography variant="title">
                    This is the title
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subheading">
                    This is what the modal can contains
                </Typography>
            </div>
        </Modal>
```

The error appears when open={true} but not when open={false}.

This is my package.json file:

```
 {
   "name": "xxxxx",
   "private": true,
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/history": "^4.6.2",
      "@types/react": "^16.3.0",
      "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
      "@types/react-hot-loader": "^3.0.6",
      "@types/react-router": "^4.0.26",
      "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.7",
      "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
      "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
      "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
      "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.5.0",
      "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
      "css-loader": "0.28.4",
      "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
      "file-loader": "0.11.2",
      "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
      "jquery": "3.2.1",
      "json-loader": "0.5.4",
      "react": "^16.3.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
      "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
      "style-loader": "0.18.2",
      "typescript": "^2.9.2",
      "url-loader": "0.5.9",
      "webpack": "2.5.1",
      "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@material-ui/core": "^1.2.1",
      "npm": "^6.1.0",
      "prop-types": "^15.6.1"
    }
  }
```

Do you have any idea about what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can't write `Boolean` as value into `render`, you should resolve this with `state`:

```
state = { open: true };
<Modal
  aria-labelledby="Title"
  aria-describedby="Description"
  open={this.state.open}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
>
###############################################################
###############################################################
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using state instead of a hardcoded boolean value and I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace your imports with the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { FaceCard } from './FaceCard'
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
```

FaceCard might also need its brackets removed.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I am importing React and ReactDom and using ReactDOM.render instead of react, but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: If you remove the <Modal> from your code, does the error persist? If so, try removing elements of the modal until we pinpoint exactly what's causing the error within the modal.

Comment: If I remove the Modal, there is no error in the console, even if I set the open property to false, there is no error. I think is something related to the Modal's render process when it is opened.

Comment: From @material-ui/core

Comment: Ok just confirming. Checking over the documentation your Modal code looks great. I'm convinced it's your imports. Mind sharing your full copy pasted imports at the top of the file?

Comment: Sure! I've added them to the question. Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out. Check my updated answer on this page. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173300/discussion-between-ruben-aguilar-and-jonnybeoulve).

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [Material-UI docs on how to use the modal](https://material-ui.com/utils/modals/), then they expect you to import with `{}`.

```
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
```

The same thing applies to your use of `<Typography>`. The import of `FaceCard` might need to not have `{}` around it, either, depending on how you are exporting it from its file.

Also, maybe npm is smart enough to figure it out, but many of your `devDependencies` are more than likely `dependencies`. For instance, react and react-dom are certainly crucial to rendering your app.